# Contional declaration in Apache httpd

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, useragent

We want to be able to set Cache-Control headers based on User-Agent in Apache

For example, if a User-Agent contains substring `foo` we want to set Cache-Control to 10 minutes. But if not set it to 1 day.

Searching around, I've found `BrowserMatch`, but that seems to only set environment variables:

```
BrowserMatch foo short-live  # Sets environment variable short-live
```

But I would like to conditionally apply a directive like `Header set ...` or `ExpiresDefault ...`

Is there a way to conditionally apply declarations? Something like:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|css)$">
  Header set Cache-control "max-age=86400"
  <IfBrowser "foo">
    Header set Cache-control "max-age=600"
  </IfBrowser>
</FilesMatch>
```

Note, `IfBrowser` is fictional. Is there any real directive that could be used like this? Thanks!

PS This is reposted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708090/contional-declaration-in-apache-httpd since that has received little activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED - yes the previous code was no good.  However, this might set you in the right direction:

```
Header set Cache-control "max-age=86400"

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent libwww short-cache
Header set Cache-control "max-age=600" env=short-cache
```

I've actually tested this, it appears to work.

Comment: No, this will not work, BrowserMatch does not work that way, I'm looking for another selector. Updating question.

Comment: Just curious if the above worked for you or not.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Can you just append "env=variable-name" to any directive? I'd like to AddEncoding or RemoveEncoding depending on the User-Agent.